# Luis + CustomVision in a single Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, image-recognition, azure-language-understanding

i am new to C# and I would like to make a bot mixing Luis services and customvision.

I would like the user to be able to send an image or text to the bot.

I am starting from the microsoft bot framework "core bot"* and the imageprocessing bot** (*https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot, **https://github.com/mandardhikari/ImageProcessingBot )

for the moment, i do have this code which is  mix between the two samples

```
#region  References
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Schema;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression;
#endregion

namespace ImageProcessingBot
{
    public class ImageProcessingBot : IBot
    {
        private readonly FlightBookingRecognizer _luisRecognizer;
        protected readonly ILogger Logger;
        private readonly ImageProcessingBotAccessors _accessors;

        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        private readonly DialogSet _dialogs;

        public ImageProcessingBot(ImageProcessingBotAccessors accessors, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _accessors = accessors ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(accessors));
            _configuration = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            _dialogs = new DialogSet(_accessors.ConversationDialogState);
        }

        public async Task OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            Activity reply = null;
            HeroCard card ;
            StringBuilder sb;

            switch(turnContext.Activity.Type)
            {
                case ActivityTypes.ConversationUpdate:
                    foreach(var member in turnContext.Activity.MembersAdded)
                    {
                        if(member.Id != turnContext.Activity.Recipient.Id)
                        {

                            reply = await CreateReplyAsync(turnContext, "Welcome. Please select and operation");
                            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken:cancellationToken);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case ActivityTypes.Message:

                    int attachmentCount =  turnContext.Activity.Attachments != null ?  turnContext.Activity.Attachments.Count() : 0;

                    var command =  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(turnContext.Activity.Text) ? turnContext.Activity.Text : await _accessors.CommandState.GetAsync(turnContext, () => string.Empty, cancellationToken);
                    command = command.ToLowerInvariant();

                    if(attachmentCount == 0)
                    {
                        var luisResult = await _luisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync<FlightBooking>(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                            switch (luisResult.TopIntent().intent)
                            {
                                case FlightBooking.Intent.Weather:
                                    // We haven't implemented the GetWeatherDialog so we just display a TODO message.
                                    var getWeatherMessageText = "TODO: get weather flow here";
                                    var getWeatherMessage = MessageFactory.Text(getWeatherMessageText, getWeatherMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(getWeatherMessage, cancellationToken);
                                    var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
                                    var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments);
                                    reply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment());


                                default:
                                    // Catch all for unhandled intents
                                    var didntUnderstandMessageText = $"Sorry, I didn't get that. Please try asking in a different way (intent was {luisResult.TopIntent().intent})";
                                    var didntUnderstandMessage = MessageFactory.Text(didntUnderstandMessageText, didntUnderstandMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
                                    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(didntUnderstandMessage, cancellationToken);
                                    break;
                            }


                    }
                    else
                    {


                        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                        Attachment attachment = turnContext.Activity.Attachments[0];

...// then it stays as in https://github.com/mandardhikari/ImageProcessingBot/blob/master/ImageProcessingBot/ImageProcessingBot/ImageProcessingBot.cs
```

I am getting these logs.

```
1>ImageProcessingBot.cs(78,41,78,46): error CS0136: A local or parameter named 'reply' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter
1>ImageProcessingBot.cs(72,33,72,67): error CS0163: Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case FlightBooking.Intent.Weather:') to another
```

I am new to c#, so any insights on the above would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The error message are telling you want to do 1) use a different variable name for the second `reply`, and 2) add a `break` statement at the end of the `case FlightBooking.Intent.Weather:` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially repeating what @stuartd says above in the comments.
The method `MessageFactory.Attachemnt` returns an `IMessageActivity` so probably best to use a second variable rather than your `Activity reply` to avoid casting

```
case FlightBooking.Intent.Weather:
 // We haven't implemented the GetWeatherDialog so we just display a TODO message.
 var getWeatherMessageText = "TODO: get weather flow here";
 var getWeatherMessage = MessageFactory.Text(getWeatherMessageText, getWeatherMessageText, InputHints.IgnoringInput);
 await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(getWeatherMessage, cancellationToken);
 var attachments = new List<Attachment>();
 meesageReply = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachments); //new variable
 messageReply.Attachments.Add(Cards.CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment());
 break;
```